# How to create a diagonal background effect, using CSS

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to create the effect shown in the following image, using CSS?

[image: [image linked here][1] with CSS?]

Basically I want to create `<div>`s that have a background split diagonally with a block color on side and white on the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` on `background`. See the following example:

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:linear-gradient(160deg, red, red 60%, white 60%, white);
}
```